# Excel; I need a named range date field to show date correctly but if there is no date the corresponding cell to be blank

Tags: excel-formula

I have a worksheet with a cell `Cost!A24` which is `date` field.  I want the same date on separate sheet Invoice.  However if there is no date in `Cost!A24` I would like if possible that on Invoice the cell be blank.

Comment: This is not a code writing service. What did you try so far? Post your code as a [mcve]! What happened when you ran it? What did you expect to happen instead? What specifically are you having problems with? What are possible date and non-date values for `Cost!A24`?

Comment: I tried using this formula ='cost'!A24 which show the date however if there is no data in the cell on cost it shows "1/0/1900" on the other sheet which looks odd

Comment: I found it posted on another web host "reject Invalid dates".  The formula should be =IF(ISBLANK(Cost!A24),"",Cost!A24)

Answer (score 1):

I am far from a expert on Excel however I found it posted on another web host "reject Invalid dates". The formula should be

```
=IF(ISBLANK(Cost!A24),"",Cost!A24)
```